# What does this merge conflict mean and how to resolve it?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I am using git. And restore stashed changes but get CONFLICT

```
$ gn
# On branch feature/improve_list
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#1  modified:   ../lib/Devel/DebugHooks.pm
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#2  both modified:   ../lib/Devel/DebugHooks/Commands.pm
#
```

Content of conflict:

```
$gd 2
index e043e7f,9cb31e5..0000000
--- a/lib/Devel/DebugHooks/Commands.pm
+++ b/lib/Devel/DebugHooks/Commands.pm
@@@ -130,12 -130,12 +130,21 @@@ sub _list 
         else {
             printf $DB::OUT  DB::can_break( $file, $line ) ? ' x' : '  ';
         }
++<<<<<<< Updated upstream


         # Print source line number
         print $DB::OUT "$line:";


++=======
++
++
++       # Print source line number
++       print $DB::OUT "$line:";
++
++
++>>>>>>> Stashed changes
         # Print source line
         (my $sl =  $source->[ $line ]) =~ s/\t/    /g; #/
         $sl =  " $sl"   if length $sl > 1; # $sl(source line) have at least "\n"
```

Why I got CONFLICT? everything is same for me
How I should edit this file to resolve this conflict (I do not understand what to keep, what to remove and what funny comments mean)
and which git commands I should use to mark this CONFLICT as resolved?

Comment: which editor your are using, some editor have plugin and there is options of git resolve conflicts

Comment: I use 'sublime text'

Comment: To remove the white space you can use the command "git checkout -p HEAD^ -- yourFile"

Comment: you can use subliemerge plugin for git conflict resolve. Below is the link 
http://www.sublimerge.com/

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have it, but more interesting how to work in console.

Answer (score 0):

There's a conflict because of different spacing used. Your stashed file has less whitespaces in front of the lines compared to the updated file.

> How I should edit this file to resolve this conflict

You can just open the file with your favorite text editor and edit it accordingly by selecting the section you want to keep.

> and which git commands I should use to mark this CONFLICT as resolved?

Once you have fixed the file you don't need any particular commands since the stashed changes aren't committed yet. So you don't need to issue any commands to resolve the conflict.

Comment: >So you don't need to issue any commands to resolve the conflict. Nope. Git issue me that it is `both modified`. I even can not do checkout for this file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a whitespace difference, probably in the line terminators.

See [the git documentation for line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) for details of how you can configure it to handle this sort of thing (it depends which platform you're using).

Depending on the platform, you probably want:

```
Linux, etc:    git config core.autocrlf input
Windows:       git config core.autocrlf true
```

This should prevent this sort of problem happening in the future.

To fix your current problem, run whichever of these config commands is appropriate for your platform, then pick either one of the sets of changes (simple approach: remove all of the lines starting with "++"). Then use:

```
git add ../lib/Devel/DebugHooks/Commands.pm
```

to mark the conflict as resolved. They you can either commit the changes, or carry on working with them.

When you eventually commit, git should fix the line terminators for you if you've run the relevant "git config" command above.

Comment: I do not think this is line terminator. Only I made changes. I stash wc, switch to different branch, do work. When I switch back and make `git stash pop` I got this. I check whitespaces and lineendings bofore post. They seem same (